# How do I solve "FTP error: 500" in MATLAB?

Tags: database, matlab, ftp, cd, mget

I want to download oceanographic data using mget in MATLAB. This is my code:

```
direc='nrt.cmems-du.eu';                    % directory from which I download the data
ftpID=ftp(direc,user,password);

cd(ftpID,'Core/INSITU_MED_NRT_OBSERVATIONS_013_035/med_multiparameter_nrt/history/BO');
mget(ftpID,'GL_PR_BO_SHIPGTSP.nc','data');  % this should download  'GL_PR_BO_SHIPGTSP.nc' into the file 'data'
```

I don't understand why I get this error:

> Error using ftp/mget (line 109)
>   FTP error: 500.

Comment: Does it work with a different client, for example using your browser?

Comment: @Hogan I am not aware of a get function in matlab which does ftp. If there is one, could you link the corresponding documentation?